# Laptop problems with UBUNTU 18.04

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, touchpad, 18.04

I have a new laptop since few months, ASUS N580V with Core i7 16 Gb RAM Nvidia Geforge 4Gb, etc. SSD, HDD, etc. with efi.

I installed suddenly UBUNTU 17.10 in dual boot with windows 10 (solving some problems of common data disk access).
LAst week I updated to 18.04 LTS and appeared several problems:
No turn-off neither restart after shut-down. Shutdown remains blocked and only possibility is to push the power button.
No monitoring of battery status in no way possible
No functioning of touchpad, only external mouse possible.

I reboot the PC in ubuntu recoveru mode, and all was ok, in recovery mode.
In recovery mode I did alll checks and all resulted ok.
Returning to normal 18.04 full mode the problems reappeared.

In windows 10 nothing changed, all ok.

What I could do?

Comment: Is your current install a fresh install? or an update?

Comment: It is update from 17.10. That was perfect...

Comment: In general, Ubuntu updates do not work correctly. The recommended way is to do a fresh Ubuntu install of the desired version. Try to NEVER update, just do a fresh install. However, if you really do not want to do a fresh install, separe the problems, and ask or search for only one at time. For example, No turn/off as one question, No restart after shut-down as another, etc.

Comment: I think that thse several problems have the same origin, I tried to look solutions to single problems, like no turn-off but none solved the problem. I have also tried to full reistall 18.04 rewriting the same partition but it does not work, it has problems in managing pertitions on two separate hd (SSD and HHD).

Comment: Ok, at the end I fully reistalled the 18.04 deleting (formatting?) the installation partition. Now I have to reinstall the programs, but this is not a problem. I hope that problems will not appear again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was finally solved fully reinstalling ubuntu 18.04 by usb key.
The problem of frozen shut down reappeared but was solved with a complete update of drivers executing sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall (in particular of nvdia geforce). The first time something was wrong in this drivers updating, the problem remained and others appeared.
BE CAREFUL to update the drivers and follow the secure updating instructions! Such as the installation reboot password, if requested.
It's curious that none of these prioblems appeared in installation 17.10 neither in 16.04 in past...

Comment: Unfortunately, new bugs come with any new release. When I use a non-LTS version like 17.10, I tend to wait until a week before the old version goes end-of-life before upgrading. That gives the 18.04 maintainers a few months to fix more of the bugs, giving me a better system.

Comment: My suggestion in this case is to include the ubuntu-drivers autoinstall in the 18.04 setting up process, if it would be possible.